# How to change language (for dates) on Tableau Cloud?

Tags: tableau-cloud

I'm creating a dashboard with Tableau Cloud. When I began to work, Tableau was in French (I work in France), but I would do my dashboard in English.

I changed the Settings (Language = English, Locale = English), but the months are still indicated in French.

Do you know how to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that when I create a new project, months are now in English (I think because I changed in the meantime the language settings).
Then I have to do again the views from scratch to correct it.